# Optimizar count()

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
using (ContextoBaseDatos contexto = new ContextoBaseDatos())
{
    IEnumerable<Modelo.Logico.Entidades.Solicitud> datos;

    Gerencia objGerencia = new Gerencia();


    if (gerencia == 0)
    {
        datos = contexto.Solicitudes.Where(s => s.GerenciaId == 11
                                            || s.GerenciaId == 12 || s.GerenciaId == 14 || s.GerenciaId == 16
                                            || s.GerenciaId == 15 || s.GerenciaId == 18 || s.GerenciaId == 21);

        //|| s.GerenciaId == 9 || s.GerenciaId == 10 );


        // )
        // || s.GerenciaId == 22
        //|| s.GerenciaId == 23 || s.GerenciaId == 24 || s.GerenciaId == 25
        //|| s.GerenciaId == 26 || s.GerenciaId == 27 || s.GerenciaId == 28
        //|| s.GerenciaId == 29 || s.GerenciaId == 30 || s.GerenciaId == 31
        //|| s.GerenciaId == 32 || s.GerenciaId == 33 || s.GerenciaId == 34
        //|| s.GerenciaId == 35 || s.GerenciaId == 36
        //);
        //var x = datos.Count();
    }
    else
    {
        datos = contexto.Solicitudes.Where(s => s.GerenciaId == gerencia).AsEnumerable();
        //var x = datos.Count();
    }

    if (cajabase != 0)
        datos = datos.Where(s => s.CajaBaseId == cajabase);

    if (tipo == 0)
        datos = datos.Where(s => (s.TipoSolicitudId == 4 || s.TipoSolicitudId == 5));
    else
        datos = datos.Where(s => s.TipoSolicitudId == tipo);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(estado))
        datos = datos.Where(s => s.Estado.NombreTipoEstado == estado);

    //count = datos.Count();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(finicio))
    {
        // DateTime fechaIni = DateTime.ParseExact(finicio.Substring(0, finicio.IndexOf('T')) + " 00:00:01", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime fechaIni = DateTime.Parse(finicio);
        datos = datos.Where(a => a.FechaCreacion >= fechaIni);
        //count = datos.Count();
    }

    //count = datos.Count();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ffin))
    {
        //DateTime fechaFin = DateTime.ParseExact(ffin.Substring(0, ffin.IndexOf('T')) + " 23:59:59", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime fechaFin = DateTime.Parse(ffin);
        datos = datos.Where(a => a.FechaCreacion <= fechaFin);

    }

    if (via != 0)
    {
        datos = datos.Where(s => (s.TipoSolicitudId == 4 && ((Modelo.Logico.Entidades.SalidaVTP)s).VTPId == via) ||
                                    (s.TipoSolicitudId == 5 && ((Modelo.Logico.Entidades.EntradaVTP)s).VTPId == via));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(albaranFiltro))
    {
        datos = datos.Where(s => (s.TipoSolicitudId == 4 && (((Modelo.Logico.Entidades.SalidaVTP)s).Albaran + "").Contains(albaranFiltro)));
    }

    //  datos = datos.Take(10);
    count = datos.Count();
    solicitudes = datos.OrderBy(sort, direction != "ASC").Skip(start).Take(limit).ToList();

    foreach (Modelo.Logico.Entidades.Solicitud solicitud in solicitudes)
    {

        EstadoVTP nueva = new EstadoVTP(solicitud.Id, solicitud.Referencia, (DateTime)solicitud.FechaCreacion, solicitud.Total)
        {
            TipoId = (int)solicitud.TipoSolicitudId,
            Alert = solicitud.Alert,
            TieneObservaciones = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(solicitud.Observaciones),
            Observaciones = solicitud.Observaciones
        };

        if (solicitud.TipoSolicitudId == 4)
            nueva.Via = ((Modelo.Logico.Entidades.SalidaVTP)solicitud).VTP.Codigo;
        else
            nueva.Via = ((Modelo.Logico.Entidades.EntradaVTP)solicitud).VTP.Codigo;

        if (solicitud.TipoSolicitudId == 4)
        {
            nueva.Albaran = ((Modelo.Logico.Entidades.SalidaVTP)solicitud).Albaran;
        }
        //Recargado por el GFP
        Modelo.Logico.Entidades.Evento recargado = solicitud.RegistroActividad.FirstOrDefault(r => r.AccionId == 5);
        if (recargado != null)
        {
            nueva.Recargado001 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_001;
            nueva.Recargado002 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_002;
            nueva.Recargado005 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_005;
            nueva.Recargado010 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_010;
            nueva.Recargado020 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_020;
            nueva.Recargado050 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_050;
            nueva.Recargado100 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_100;
            nueva.Recargado200 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_200;
            nueva.Recargado5 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Billete_5;
            nueva.Recargado10 = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Billete_10;
            nueva.TotalGFP = recargado.DesgloseFacial.Total;
        }

        //Albaran de la via
        Modelo.Logico.Entidades.Evento albaran = solicitud.RegistroActividad.FirstOrDefault(r => r.AccionId == 6);
        if (recargado != null)
        {
            nueva.Albaran001 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_001;
            nueva.Albaran002 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_002;
            nueva.Albaran005 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_005;
            nueva.Albaran010 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_010;
            nueva.Albaran020 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_020;
            nueva.Albaran050 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_050;
            nueva.Albaran100 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_100;
            nueva.Albaran200 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Moneda_200;
            nueva.Albaran5 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Billete_5;
            nueva.Albaran10 = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Billete_10;
            nueva.TotalVia = albaran.DesgloseFacial.Total;
        }

        resultado.Add(nueva);
    }

}
```

El problema lo tengo en esta linea...

```
count = datos.Count();
```

Me va muy lento, se os ocurre otra forma de hacerlo?

Saludos!

Comment: Que quiere decir que te va lento? y como sabes que justamente esa instruccion es la que tarda?

Comment: Ienumerable tiene que recorrer toda la lista para contarla... tenes muchos elementos? demasiados?

Comment: Si demasiados elementos en el IEnumerable. Pero son los que tienen que ser. Y no puedo cargar menos.. por eso.. no se como hacer para que los recorra más rápido @gbianchi

Comment: @gbianchi lento por que me da a veces error de tiempo y se me para la aplicación. Tarda como 7 minutos... :(

Comment: sé que es está por que al depurar es donde se queda un buen rato...

Comment: De donde salen los datos? no se pueden poner en otro tipo de coleccion? una base de datos tardaria segundos en contarlos...

Comment: y de cuantos elementos estamos hablando?

Comment: Has probado de, en vez de hacerlo con IEnumerable hacerlo con un List<>?
En [este enlace](https://gist.github.com/kspearrin/8dbf7d76d6fd21a8d861dc9c472547d4), demuestran que IEnumerable puede ser mas lento que List<> o Array

Comment: Gracias @Marc le doy un ojo.

Comment: @gbianchi salen de una bd de datos. No se si pueden sacarse de otra forma. Voy a ver de la forma que dice Marc

Comment: la base de datos va a ser mucho mas rapido si haces un query directo...

Comment: le pusiste un stopwatch para medir el tiempo sin depurar con f5 o f10? De cuanto registros estas hablando? deberiamos hablar de cientos de miles de registros para se se demore o millones.

Comment: Si el problema esta en el count, entonces se relaciona con la ejecucion de la consulta a la db, quizas deberias ver si falta crear algun `indice` en la db por alguno de los campos que usas en los filtros de entity framework